# find identical keys with different values from two text files

Tags: bash, awk, vimdiff

I have two files which have data in a format like this:

cat File1.txt

```
A: 1
B: 2
C: 3
D: 4
E: 5
```

cat File2.txt

```
A: 10
B: 2
C: 30
D: 4
F: 6
```

I was wondering how I could print the diff for common keys like:

```
A: 1, 10
C: 3, 30
```

Comment: How much do you know about awk? Click the [tag:awk] tag above, then click the [Learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) link for a brief primer.  Have you made any attempts to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
awk -F":" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} FNR!=NR && a[$1] && a[$1]!=$2{print $1":"a[$1]","$2}' File1.txt File2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems there are no duplicates in the file, this should do:

```
$ awk '{if(($1 in a)&&$2!=a[$1])print $1,a[$1] ", " $2;else a[$1]=$2}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
A: 1, 10
C: 3, 30
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{
    if(($1 in a) && $2!=a[$1])    # if $1 already seen and $2 not equal to previous
        print $1,a[$1] ", " $2    # output
    else 
        a[$1]=$2                  # else store the value as seen for the first time
}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=", " }
NR==FNR {
    a[$1] = $2
    next
}
($1 in a) && (a[$1] != $2) {
    print $0, a[$1]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
A: 1, 10
C: 3, 30
```